# *Accurately* calculating text height in Cocoa (for Mac, not iOS)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

How can I calculate the height of a string within a particular label (NSTextField), for some given fixed width?

I Googled up various methods and tried [this method from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextLayout/Tasks/StringHeight.html). It works, except that the height becomes one line too short for longer strings. Thus, there appear to be some inaccuracies in the present methods.

I also had the same issue with some other code I Googled up.

Does someone here have any *accurate* code for finding text height (given a particular width)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I solved the problem using the NS(Attributed)String+Geometrics category provided at http://www.sheepsystems.com/sourceCode/sourceStringGeometrics.html Within the header file of that category is a good explanation of how these things work. Specifically, they mention that one should use NSTextView instead of NSTextField because it's virtually impossible to get an accurate height for the latter.

Thus, I replaced my NSTextField with NSTextView. First, I made my NSTextView look like my NSTextField with this code:

```
[textView setEditable:YES];
[textView insertText:someString];
[textView setFont:[NSFont fontWithName:@"Lucida Grande"
   size:11] range:NSMakeRange(0,[someString length])];
[textView setEditable:NO];
[textView setSelectable:NO];
```

Then I got the height with this code:

```
NSDictionary *attributes
  = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
     [textView font],NSFontAttributeName,nil];
NSAttributedString *attributedString
  = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:
     [textView string] attributes:attributes];
CGFloat height = [attributedString heightForWidth:
                 [textView frame].size.width];
```

The height does indeed turn out to be accurate for NSTextView.

I may have omitted some minor details, but you get the picture. I hope this helps someone out there.

Comment: Great work solving your own problem. This looks like useful info, too. Please don't forget to accept one of these answers so that the question does not appear as "Unanswered".

Comment: Yeah, I'll do that. But I have to wait 2 days after posting (22 hours from now) before I can do that.

Comment: `[textView setFont:[NSFont systemFontOfSize:13] range:NSMakeRange(0,[someString length])];` This is the most important line here. With out it you'll get wrong heights **even** if the text view in the interface builder is set to the same font and size. I also had to write this line after every `setString` in my tableview or else things would get funky.

Comment: @Segev Fantastic, thank you! I will still getting odd height values (twice the size of the actual text). I tried your method of setting the label font *after* setting the text string and it worked perfectly. Weird bugs in Xcode/macOS I guess... :/

Answer (score 8):

(a solution in Swift is at the end of the post)

I tried all of these methods and none worked for me. The 'official' way (as mentioned by OP) was off most of the time for my `NSTextField`. Switching to `NSTextView` was impossible because of XCode/IB *always* crashing after adding a "NSTextView in an NSScrollView".

Long story short, I found this easy way to determine the height of my `NSTextField` but this can be very easily adapted to width.

```
CGFloat minHeight = [((NSTextFieldCell *)[yourTextField cell]) cellSizeForBounds:NSMakeRect(0, 0, YOUR_MAX_WIDTH, FLT_MAX)].height;
```

This code has worked for every single test-case that failed with the other methods. I hope this helps someone. It always makes me feel so darn stupid when I take 2 hours to find the solution to a seemingly easy problem.

**SLIGHT EDIT**: Upon closer inspection this only works if you read the `stringValue` of the `NSTextField` before I ask the cell to calculate its height. So I added the following **nonsensical** line before the actual calculation:

```
[yourTextField setStringValue:yourTextField.stringValue];
```

I know this is *really really* bad but at this point I don't care anymore. I just want a reliable solution. Feel free to downvote me *or better yet*: suggest a better solution.

---

**Solution in Swift** (thank you iphaaw for bringing this to my attention!)

```
myTextField.cell!.cellSizeForBounds(NSMakeRect(CGFloat(0.0), CGFloat(0.0), width, CGFloat(FLT_MAX))).height
```

Comment: Thanks for this easy solution. But why the cast? It's totally okay without. For me it works without the "nonsensical" line.

Comment: vigorouscoding Where should i put this code to work ? I put this in `cellforview` but ut didn't worked

Answer (score 5):

Thanks indeed to iphaaw and Enchilada for this really cool little solution.  I found it worked so well at setting row heights etc that I converted iphaaw's Swift into a couple of NSTextField extensions.

```swift
extension NSTextField {
    func bestheight(text: String, width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        self.stringValue = text
        let getnumber = self.cell!.cellSizeForBounds(NSMakeRect(CGFloat(0.0), CGFloat(0.0), width, CGFloat(Float.greatestFiniteMagnitude))).height
        
        return getnumber
    }
}

extension NSTextField {
    func bestwidth(text: String, height: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        self.stringValue = text
        let getnumber = self.cell!.cellSizeForBounds(NSMakeRect(CGFloat(0.0), CGFloat(0.0), CGFloat(Float.greatestFiniteMagnitude), height)).width
        
        return getnumber
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is [ArtbyKGH's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38553592/3151675) for Swift 4+:

```
extension NSTextField {
    func bestHeight(for text: String, width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        stringValue = text
        let height = cell!.cellSize(forBounds: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)).height

        return height
    }

    func bestWidth(for text: String, height: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        stringValue = text
        let width = cell!.cellSize(forBounds: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: .greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: height)).width

        return width
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [NSString Application Kit Additions Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSString_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html). It seems like `– sizeWithAttributes:` or  `– boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:` could do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Vigorouscoding's answer works so well! Is this really bad? It seems to work perfectly. Finally after spending many hours of trying other solutions.

Here is my Swift translation of the code:

```
myTextField.cell!.cellSizeForBounds(NSMakeRect(CGFloat(0.0), CGFloat(0.0), width, CGFloat(FLT_MAX))).height
```

Please don't up vote this answer. Upvote vigorouscoding's entry instead.