# How to have font in NSTextView string adjust to NSTextView size

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextview

How do I have the text of an NSTextView adjust to fit the contents of the box without having to need to scroll? For instance, if the user typed in a long string and if I later display the string back as an NSTextView, how can I make it so that the font decreases to a small enough size to fit the box?

Answer (score 0):

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518147/accurately-calculating-text-height-in-cocoa-for-mac-not-ios), the accepted answer provides a way to measure the height of text in an NSTextView.
Using that, you could cycle through different font sizes (i.e. from 8-18) from largest to smallest stopping & selecting the first one which fits the NSTextView height.

(totally untested) code:

```
- (void)autoAdjustFontSizeForTextView:(NSTextView *)myView
{
    int minFont = 8;
    int maxFont = 18;

    for (int i=maxFont; i>=minFont; i--)
    {
      NSFont *myFont = [NSFont fontWithName:@"Lucida Grande" size:i];
        int textHeight = [self heightOfStringInTextView:myView withFont:myFont];
        if (textHeight < [myView frame].size.height)
        {
            // set view font
            [textView setFont:myFont];
            return;
        }
    }
}

- (int)heightOfStringInTextView:(NSTextView *)myView withFont:(NSFont *)myFont
{
    NSDictionary *attributes
      = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
         myFont,NSFontAttributeName,nil];
    NSAttributedString *attributedString
      = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:
         [myView string] attributes:attributes];
    CGFloat height = [attributedString heightForWidth:
                     [myView frame].size.width];
    return (int)height;
}
```

Comment: attributedString does not have a method for "heightForWidth:". Can you explain the line?

Comment: As pointed out in the linked question, you'll need the [NS(Attributed)String+Geometrics](https://github.com/jerrykrinock/CategoriesObjC/tree/master/NS(Attributed)String%2BGeometrics) category.

Comment: the "heightOfStringInTextView" does not return anything despite it being written as "int". I tried having it return the height, but that resulted in errors in the program. Did you get this code to work?

Comment: Method did not return anything in fact.. edited that in the answer, as well as the method call. As I mentioned, I did not test the code.