# How to make button position in relation to each other?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to make a FAQ, so when you click on a button it replaces the text with the question and answer. I am using this code to replace the text:

```
ViewContoller.m

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonTest;
- (IBAction)ButtonTest:(id)sender;

@end

ViewController.h

- (IBAction)ButtonTest:(id)sender
{
    if ([_buttonTest.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"This is the Question No1?"])
    {
        [sender setTitle:@"This is the Question No1? This is question No1 answer that enter code herehas a fair bit of content" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else
    {
        [sender setTitle:@"What age is This is the Question No1?" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

When the botton is clicked it all works fine, but the text is displayed over the top of the second question.

Does anyone know how to make this move down to accommodate the answer, but then back up when it is clicked again?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should manage it manually by shifting the frame of all the questions down from the clickable question and you should increase the height of that clickable button according to the text you are assigning them.

Again when you click that answered button decrease the height and shift the downside questions frame to up side.

Use scrollview to add buttons and increase and decrease the content size and as the button click.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set up each of your Questions using AutoLayout, so that each one's Top Space constraint is related to the previous' bottom line (apart from the first one of course, the actual value can be anything you wish):

   [image]
2. Programmatically adjust your Question's height when the button is clicked.
   Optional: In case you need to measure the required height of the question+answer, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518147/accurately-calculating-text-height-in-cocoa-for-mac-not-ios) might be of help. Essentially what you'll need to do is use the [NSString+Geometrics Category](http://www.sheepsystems.com/sourceCode/sourceStringGeometrics.html) like so:

   ```
   NSDictionary *attributes
     = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        [questionField font],NSFontAttributeName,nil];
   NSAttributedString *attributedString
     = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:
        [questionField title] attributes:attributes];
   // Here below the height of the string
   CGFloat height = [attributedString heightForWidth:
                    [questionField frame].size.width];
   ```

Answer (score -1):

If I am understanding your scenario correctly you want to remove the button and show your text in the same place where your button was.

I think you can place your UILabel and UIButton at the same place and keep your label hidden.And when the button is tapped unhide your label and hide the button this would be better than changing the text of your button.

Comment: Basically I my list of questions to display like this:
 Questions 1?
 Question 2?
 Question3?
 Question4?
 
 Then when you click is displays the answer inbetween the questions:
 
 Questions 1?
 This is the answer to question 1 with various lines of text depending on the answer!
 Question 2?
 Question3?
 Question4?
 
 Then when you click the button again it displays back to the original list!
 
 Thanks

Comment: sorry the list of question was supposed to display in a row!