# Dynamic row height for NSTableView in Swift/Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, swift3

EDIT: The question was not answered by the linked reply. I'm still stuck on this...

I've got a table that I use for chat messages. Each message is a variably-sized box including some text. I want the row height in my table to dynamically change depending on the size of the message box.

If I tick 'automatic' for size style in IB, it makes all of the rows have tiny heights. It looks like iOS have UITableViewAutomaticDimension which automatically scales the table, but I can't find anything like that for NSTableView.

I know there's an option to create the following function:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, heightOfRow row: Int) -> CGFloat
{
       return 50 // ????
}
```

and I am able to set the row height using that (the above sets all of my rows to height 50), but I don't know how to make it dependent on the size of the text in my box. How can I do this efficiently?

Comment: Thanks very much for your replies! The answer for me is within Sunkas' elaboration on Corbin's post. But both are in Objective-C and I'm having a hard time working out how to translate them to Swift. Is there any chance anyone could post the Swift version as an answer here?

Comment: Also, will Corbin's answer resize the rows when the window is resized too or only when the table is redrawn? The latter is problematic, because if the user shrinks the window horizontally then the messages will become taller and thinner, as one would expect...

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution

First you set up a NSTextfield in code.  This is a "virtual" field in as it is never actually drawn

```
    var fakefield = NSTextField()  
// Set the fontsize etc to be what you will use in the table
```

Then in the heightOfRow function

```
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, heightOfRow row: Int) -> CGFloat {

    let item = yourArray[row] 
    let fakefield.stringValue = item 
    // exactly how you get the text out of your data array depends on how you set it up

    let yourHeight = fakefield.cell!.cellSizeForBounds(NSMakeRect(CGFloat(0.0), CGFloat(0.0), yourWidth, CGFloat(FLT_MAX))).height
    // yourWidth = the width of your cell as CGFloat.  

    return yourHeight
}
```

more details and NSTextfield extensions can be found [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518147/accurately-calculating-text-height-in-cocoa-for-mac-not-ios/38553592#38553592).  Note this answer is in Swift 2.3  (haven't made the plunge to 3 yet)