# macOS cocoa TableView with variable Row-Height and custom cells

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, tableview, swift4

**Situation**
I want to create a News-Article table within a macOS Cocoa application. (see image below)
Each Cell consists of two labels. One for the header and one for the main-content.

**Problem**
Now the length of the news-bodies and the width of the whole TableView is variable. I want to have a variable height on each Row/Cell depending on the size of the labels in it.

**What we tried**
We tried the following: 
We have a 
TableView

```
 -> TableColumn
  -> Custom View
   -> LabelHeader
   -> LabelBody
```

The RowSizeStyle Property on TableView is set to "Automatic"

The cells are populated with a custom class. Basically we tried to implement this StackOverflow solution: [Link to Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47065227) -> which did not work for us.

(And many more solutions we could not get to run)

**Question**
Can anyone provide a working tutorial or solution for this problem? Or at least a promising approach?

**PS** I use XCode 9.4.1 and Swift 4 on macOS 10.13.5

Any help gladly appreciated, Thank you!

[image: img]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a modern cocoa application you would use **NSLayoutConstraint** to implement dynamic height of a table view cell. The tricky part would be to get the height of the text that you can set the height of the constrain. This could be done being using an **NSTextView** instead of NSTextField and asking the layout manager for the current height.

```
NSRect usedRect = [[textView layoutManager] usedRectForTextContainer:[self textContainer]];
float newHeight = usedRect.size.height;
```

I used this in an objective c application some years ago so if you have further questions please let me know.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I will try your suggestion and probably come back with questions.

Comment: Thank you Marc! We managed to succeed with a combination of your help and this Stackoverflow Post: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39920958/7274172)